# Two non-isomorphic intuitionistic Kripke frames satisfying different formulas.

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I am struggling with the following problem:

Being given two non-isomorphic intuitionistic Kripke frames $F_1$ and $F_2$ there is a formula $\phi$ such as:
$$
F_1 \models \phi\ and\ F_2 \not \models \phi.
$$
I would like to use this result to prove that logics (considered as set of formulas) of two non-isomorphic intuitionistic Kripke frames are different.

Comment: I don't quite understand - are you trying to show that *any* two nonisomorphic intuitionistic Kripke frames yield different logics? If so, that's false (just count the number of frames vs. the number of logics).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Noah in the comment.
You cannot find $\phi$ in general, not even for finite frames.
You can find trivial examples by yourself.

However, if $\phi$ exists, then your final claim follows immediately from the definition of the logic of an intuitionistic Kripke frame.

You can find $\phi$ if $F_i$ are rooted and finite.
(I think there are multiple ways to prove this.
I see it in the following way.
If $F_i$ satisfy the same formulas, then $F_1$ is a generated subframe of a bounded morphic image (also called reduction) of a disjoint union of copies of $F_2$, and vice versa -- this is Birkhoff's theorem from universal algebra in action.
This implies $|F_1|\leq|F_2|$ and $|F_2|\leq|F_1|$ and it becomes clear that $F_1\cong F_2$.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !